# Prevent system-wide and virtualenv ipython from using the same directory for configuration

Tags: python, configuration, virtualenv, ipython, rc

Recently, I started looking into `virtualenv` but ran into
problems with the configuration of `ipython`.
I created the virtual environment using

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages ENV
```

From within ENV (i.e. after `source bin/activate`),
I installed `ipython`.

```
pip install ipython
```

However, after having used `ipython` from within ENV,
I got a problem using the ``normal'' version.
Basically, I get the following warnings:

```
WARNING: Configuration file ipythonrc not found. Ignoring request.
```

and

```
WARNING: Problems loading configuration file 'ipythonrc'
Starting with default -bare bones- configuration.
```

The system-wide `ipython` is version 0.10 (still using Kubuntu 10.04 LTS),
whereas the one inside ENV is 0.13.
Apparently, there has been a change in the configuration.
If I remove the folder `$HOME/.ipython/` and start up the system-wide
installation, everything works fine again.
But as soon as I launch `ipython` from within ENV, the content of
`$HOME/.ipython/` is replaced and in particular, the file `ipythonrc`
is removed.

So my question is, how can I prevent both `ipython`s from
using the same folder `$HOME/.ipython/` for configuration purposes?

Answer (score 3):

Set the environment variable `$IPYTHONDIR` to something in your virtual-env.  The IPython config location is determined relative to that, so you just need to add `export IPYTHONDIR="$VIRTUAL_ENV/.ipython"` or similar to your activate (and appropriate inverse on deactivate).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a different configuration file for the virtualenv version.

One option to do this is by adding an alias in the `bin/activate` file.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
alias ipython="ipython -rcfile $VIRTUAL_ENV/.ipythonrc"
```

Alternatively, setting the `IPYTHONDIR` variable to `$VIRTUAL_ENV/.ipython/` should also work. This option appears undocumented in the manpage but the code shows that it is using that.